# Using ITR utility on Ubuntu or its flavors

Tags: java, javafx

## Problem:

I want to use ITR e-filing utility (India's Income Tax Return e-filing utility) on Ubuntu or any of its flavors.

## What I've tried:

1. I tried installing `java` (OpenJDK 11), and installing OpenJFX using Synaptic Manager. It still shows following error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New answer

Income Tax Department recommends using Java version 8 Update 51 (See [this PDF file](https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/StaticPDF/How_to_use_ITR_Utilities_Other.pdf)).

**Step 1:** Download openjdk-8-jre using Synaptic Package Manager or command line as below:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

**Step 2:** Install OpenJFX components of v8 series. It can be done through command line:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

Try running the ITR.sh file (need to make it executable first!). Proceed to Step 3 if error occurs.

**Step 3:** Ensure that Java's version 8 is being used with OpenJFX. Type in command line:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You may be greeted with something like:

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

Enter `2` to use Java 8 as it is the only one that runs the income tax utility.

> Thanks to Geetu Vaswani for his amazing [blog post](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2020/05/09/how-to-use-india-income-tax-java-utilities-on-linux/).

## Use ITR utility

Find `ITR.sh` file that comes in the e-filing utility.

Right click on the file `ITR.sh` --> Go to `Properties` --> Click `Permissions` tab --> Make the file executable --> Click `Apply` then `OK`.

Click `ITR.sh` --> Execute the file (preferably in terminal) --> Voila!

***Note**: You may need to edit ITR.sh file (simply right click and open with default text editor) and add `#!/bin/bash` at the start of the file. After doing so, `ITR.sh` file should look like:*

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ITR-2_AY201920_PR3.2.jar
```

## Previous answer

### Download supported Java version

Income Tax Department recommends using Java version 8 Update 51 (See [this PDF file](https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/StaticPDF/How_to_use_ITR_Utilities_Other.pdf)). You need to have account on Oracle website to be able to [download older (archived) Java versions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html). In case you do not have an account on Oracle website or do not want to open one, head over to [this index website by CERN](http://monalisa.cern.ch/MONALISA/download/java/) and click on *jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz* for 64 bit version or *jdk-8u66-linux-i586.tar.gz* for 32bit version (JDK v8u66 is slightly upper version but shouldn't matter much). This answer takes *jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz* as the downloaded file. If you have downloaded 32 bit version just change the file name to *jdk-8u66-linux-i586.tar.gz*.

### Install Java

Method 1 (Quick):

Copy:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir -p /usr/java && sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/java && JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/ && sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/java 20000 && sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/javac 20000
```

Go to the directory (folder), where you have downloaded *jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz*.

Create a file named `RUN.sh`. Open it with default text editor (like gedit, kwrite) and paste the above copied contents in it. Save the file.

Right click on the file `RUN.sh` --> Go to `Properties` --> Click `Permissions` tab --> Make the file executable --> Click `Apply` then `OK`.

Execute the file in terminal (press <kbd>F4</kbd>, and type `sh ./RUN.sh`) --> Type password when prompted (you may not even see asterisks when you type, it is normal)

Restart your computer.

Method 2 (Explained):

Go to the directory, where you have downloaded *jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz*, say Downloads, which gives us path of directory: `/home/*user*/Downloads`.

Open terminal window by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Type following commands one by one:

Create a directory in your file system, in a manner so that it wouldn't interfere with OpenJDK in case it is installed in future: `/usr/java`

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/java
```

Type password when prompted (you may not even see asterisks when you type, it is normal).

Extract the files you just downloaded in that directory:

```
sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/java
```

Set your JAVA_HOME environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/
```

Set up installed Java (Oracle JDK v8u51) at a higher priority (here 20000), so that in case another JDK (say OpenJDK) is installed in future, Oracle JDK v8u51 continues to be used.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/java 20000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/javac 20000
```

Restart your computer.

### Use ITR utility

Find `ITR.sh` file that comes in the e-filing utility.

Right click on the file `ITR.sh` --> Go to `Properties` --> Click `Permissions` tab --> Make the file executable --> Click `Apply` then `OK`.

Click `ITR.sh` --> Execute the file (preferably in terminal) --> Voila!

***Note**: You may need to edit ITR.sh file (simply right click and open with default text editor) and add `#!/bin/bash` at the start of the file. After doing so, `ITR.sh` file should look like:*

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ITR-2_AY201920_PR3.2.jar
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since oracle took java they made it complicated. I face same issue and sorted out. I have another easy solution.

Download `java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-jdk_8.262.10-1_amd64.deb` from amazon and install as:

```
sudo dpkg -i java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-jdk_8.262.10-1_amd64.deb
```

It works perfectly.

$ ./ITR.sh

I got correct output for ITR utility like this pic
[image: I got correct output for ITR utility like this pic]

Comment: Hi @Vijay, thanks for input. Could you also provide link to download the file mentioned?

Comment: I think we can find the mentioned deb file here: https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/releases

Comment: alert: I took a later deb version and the ITR jar didn't work with that. Uninstalled it from sofware center and now installed the 8.262.10-1 as mentioned here. Set that java as the active version. still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve JavaFX Runtime Missing Components:
The problem occurs as latest JDK/JRE do not come with JavaFX. The fix what I have just found out is:

1. DOWNLOAD the javaFX sdk. I did it from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/. Please ensure you choose the linux version for your Ubuntu installation
2. UNZIP
3. SAVE the unzipped folder in your library. I did it in "/usr/lib"
4. EXPORT THE PATH of javaFX by "export" command. In my case:
   "export PATH_TO_FX=/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib"
5. UPDATE ITR.sh to include the path of javaFX. After updating mine, it looks like:
   `#java -jar ITR-2_AY202021_PR3.2.jar \n export PATH_TO_FX=/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib \n java -jar --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules  javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web ITR-2_AY202021_PR3.2.jar` 
   Please note, how the module path is added to point to $PATH_TO_FX
6. Run ITR utility script: ./ITR.sh

Please revert back to me if it still does not work.

- Niloy

Answer (score 0):

I referred above suggestion given by Vijay and it worked like magic.Thanks Vijay!

I followed below steps on my macOS:

1. Tried by downloading amazon-corretto-8.282.08.1-macosx-x64.tar.gz.
2. Added `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. sh ITR.sh

I was able to launch the utility successfully

Comment: I won't expect people to search through Ask **Ubuntu** for questions/answers related to macOS. However, you can post your answer on [apple.se].